# Pandas - drop row containing Nan and then drop any associated rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns: 'age' and 'name'. Which looks like this (when opened in notepad):

```
,age,name
0,18,Bill
1,22,Harry
2,Nan,Bill
4,5,William
```

(the first column is an index)

I need to drop any rows with Nan in the age column and also drop any rows which have the same name in the name column. For example, in the snippet of my data frame I would want to drop both rows with Bill in as one of the ages contains Nan

Currently i have this:

```
df_no_dups = dp[dp.isfinite(dp['age'])]
```

This is the first part but am stuck on removing the other rows with the same name  as the row containing Nan

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with boolean mask created by [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for test if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.all.html) values per groups have no missing value:

```
df1 = df[df['age'].notnull().groupby(df['name']).transform('all')]
```

Or check missing values, test if at least one `True` per group and last invert boolean mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df[~df['age'].isnull().groupby(df['name']).transform('any')]
```

---

```
print (df1)
    age     name
1  22.0    Harry
3   5.0  William
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['age'].notnull())
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: age, dtype: bool

print (df['age'].notnull().groupby(df['name']).transform('all'))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: age, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you, what is the purpose of the transform('any')?

Comment: I edit answer, it is better? If something unclear, give me know, I try explain more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name'],keep=False)
df[(df['age'].notnull()] #or df[(df['age']!='Nan')] (as your input Contains Nan as string)
```

Explanation:

First remove the duplicates and pass `keep=False` to remove all duplicates. Then filter for NaN.

Output:

```
  age     name
1  22    Harry
4   5  William
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep=False)
df = df.dropna(subset=['age'])
```

Edit: this works for null values, if Nan is a string as pointed by @Mohamed then use the answer provided by him.

Comment: It's similar to  my answer